# Get and show data from MySQL of a single user in the Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working on an Android app where I save the data in a MySQL database and then I have to display it in the `TextView` of the Android app.

When the user clicks on the 'Information' `button` he must view all his information.

The problem is that I don't understand how to do it, I tried to use the code of this tutorial "https://androidjson.com/android-php-insert-display-select-update-delete/", but the problem is that I don't I have a View list, I only have one button and I can't understand how to show the data of a single user.

The android app it shows nothing, the data does not arrive.

I also tried to passed the user's id in the previous activity, but then I don't know how to show that user's data in the next activity.

My table in MySQL is called `Restaurants` and has 11 fields.

- idR
- LocalName
- MediumPrize
- Country
- Region
- Province
- Cap
- Address
- Email
- Telephone Number

My php code is :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'config.php';

 $idR= r285602265407430;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Ristoranti WHERE idR = '$idR'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 echo 'culo';

 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

My Java code is :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Modifica_info_base extends AppCompatActivity {

    HttpParse_info httpParse = new HttpParse_info();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    // Http Url For Filter Student Data from Id Sent from previous activity.
    String HttpURL = "http://provaord.altervista.org/OrdPlace/InformazioniRistorante/filter_info_base.php";

    String finalResult ;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    String ParseResult ;
    HashMap<String,String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();
    String FinalJSonObject ;
    String text;
    TextView tNomeRistorante, tPrezzoMedio, tNazione, tRegione, tCitta, tProvincia, tCap, tIndirizzo, tEmail, tNumero;
    String Nomeristorante, Prezzomedio, Nazione, Regione, Citta, Provincia, Cap, Indirizzo, Email, Numero;
    Button UpdateButton;
    String TempItem;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog2;
    EditText idR;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modifica_info_base);

        tNomeRistorante = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_ristorante);
        tPrezzoMedio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_prezzo_medio);
        tNazione = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_nazione);
        tRegione = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_regione);
        tCitta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_citta);
        tProvincia = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_provincia);
        tCap = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_cap);
        tIndirizzo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_indirizzo);
        tEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_email);
        tNumero = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_numero_telefono);

        idR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5id);

        UpdateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_modifica_info_base);

        TempItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("ListViewValue");

        final String text= idR.getEditableText().toString();

        //Calling method to filter Student Record and open selected record.
        HttpWebCall(text);

        UpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Modifica_info_base.this,Messagge_ristoratore.class);

                // Sending Student Id, Name, Number and Class to next UpdateActivity.
                intent.putExtra("idR", String.valueOf(idR));
                intent.putExtra("NomeLocale", Nomeristorante);
                intent.putExtra("PrezzoMedio", Prezzomedio);
                intent.putExtra("Nazione", Nazione);
                intent.putExtra("Regione", Regione);
                intent.putExtra("Citta", Citta);
                intent.putExtra("Provincia", Provincia);
                intent.putExtra("Cap", Cap);
                intent.putExtra("Indirizzo", Indirizzo);
                intent.putExtra("Email", Email);
                intent.putExtra("Telefono", Numero);


                startActivity(intent);

                // Finishing current activity after opening next activity.
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    //Method to show current record Current Selected Record
    public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem){

        class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Modifica_info_base.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                pDialog.dismiss();

                //Storing Complete JSon Object into String Variable.
                FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg ;

                //Parsing the Stored JSOn String to GetHttpResponse Method.
                new GetHttpResponse(Modifica_info_base.this).execute();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                ResultHash.put("idR",params[0]);

                ParseResult = httpParse.postRequest(ResultHash, HttpURL);

                return ParseResult;
            }
        }

        HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

        httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
    }


    // Parsing Complete JSON Object.
    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                if(FinalJSonObject != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing Student Name, Phone Number, Class into Variables.
                            Nomeristorante = jsonObject.getString("NomeLocale").toString() ;
                            Prezzomedio = jsonObject.getString("PrezzoMedio").toString() ;
                            Nazione = jsonObject.getString("Nazione").toString() ;
                            Regione = jsonObject.getString("Regione").toString() ;
                            Citta = jsonObject.getString("Citta").toString() ;
                            Provincia = jsonObject.getString("Provincia").toString() ;
                            Cap = jsonObject.getString("Cap").toString() ;
                            Indirizzo = jsonObject.getString("Indirizzo").toString() ;
                            Email = jsonObject.getString("Email").toString() ;
                            Numero = jsonObject.getString("Telefono").toString() ;

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {

            tNomeRistorante.setText(Nomeristorante);
            tPrezzoMedio.setText(Prezzomedio);
            tNazione.setText(Nazione);
            tRegione.setText(Regione);
            tCitta.setText(Citta);
            tCap.setText(Cap);
            tProvincia.setText(Provincia);
            tIndirizzo.setText(Indirizzo);
            tEmail.setText(Email);
            tNumero.setText(Numero);


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [OKhttp3](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) library. its easy for handle web service calls. and see this tutorial about get data from json encoded text [Json parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)